# how to handle angular's put request of JSON object in spring boot?

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot, http, put

I am trying to mock the environment which is used in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fdf5aTYRW0E&t=3686s) you tube video. Here he uses [this](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) as a back end to store and retrieve data from angular front end.

I wanted to do the same thing using spring boot as my backed and make rest calls from front end (Angular).

I am successfully getting the GET requests output. But not able to work with PUT requests.

I want to send a JSON object to the server and server should use it to do some action.

### Client Side

My **Angular code** to put the JSON object looks like this:

#### Service

```
updateTodo(todo:Todo):Observable<boolean>{
   return this.http.put<boolean>('http://localhost:8080/udateJsonData',todo,httpOptions);
}
```

My *todo* variable's class definition which is in above put request is:

#### Model

```
export class Todo{
    id:number;
    title:string;
    completed:boolean;
}
```

#### HttpOptions

```
const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
}
```

### Backend

And in **spring boot** on the server side. I have a rest call mapped method which looks like this:

#### RequestBody(Model)

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class RequestBody {
   @JsonProperty int id;
   @JsonProperty String title;
   @JsonProperty boolean completed;
}
```

#### Controller

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/udateJsonData", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody boolean udateJsonData(RequestBody requestBody) {
  System.out.println(requestBody.title);
  return false;
}
```

Problem is i am getting the sysout as ***null***.
I tried to debug, and found that my ***requestBody*** itself is null.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a sort of POJO object in Java (for example `TodoDTO`) which has the same structure and types as the one in Angular.

Then you used the `@RequestBody` annotation in your put method params:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/udateJsonData", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody boolean udateJsonData(@RequestBody TodoDTO todo) {
    System.out.println(todo.title);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@RequestBody` annotation to get the data

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/udateJsonData", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody boolean udateJsonData(@RequestBody RequestBody requestBody) {
  System.out.println(requestBody.title);
  return false;
}
```

> You could actually use *@PutMapping*

```java
@PutMapping(value = "udateJsonData", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public boolean udateJsonData(@RequestBody RequestBody requestBody) {
   System.out.println(requestBody.title);
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Error message in my browsers console. ""JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.response.RESTMapping$RequestBody` (although at least one Creator exists): can only instantiate non-static inner class by using default, no-argument constructor; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.response.RESTMapping$RequestBody` (although at least one Creator exists): can only instantiate non-static inner class by using default, no-argument constructor
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]""

Comment: It cannot create an instance `Cannot construct instance of com.response.RESTMapping$RequestBody` add `No-Arg constructor` to the `RequestBody ` , which will be `public RequestBody() {}`